# mysql crashes when accessing database after upgrade from 5.5 to 5.7

Tags: mysql, database, innodb

After upgrading mysql from 5.5 to 5.7, one of innodb databases seems corrupted.

```
mysqldump -u root -p mydatabase > mydatabase.sql Enter password:
mysqldump: Error: 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query' when trying to dump tablespaces
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'ndbinfo\_version'': MySQL server has gone away (2006)

mysqlcheck -u root -p mydatabase
Enter password:
mysqlcheck: Got error: 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query when executing 'CHECK TABLE ... '
```

The mysql log shows this error:

```
[ERROR] InnoDB: Trying to access page number 1122710 in space 154, space name mydatabase/mytable, which is outside the tablespace bounds. Byte offset 0, len 8192, i/o type read. If you get this error at mysqld startup, please check that your my.cnf matches the ibdata files that you have in the MySQL server.
[ERROR] InnoDB: Server exits.
```

Now, I cannot dump the database for recovery nor repair the database. How can I do? The database is a compressed one.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run [mysql_upgrade](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-upgrade.html) after you updated the software?

Comment: yes, I ran mysql_upgrade but the last message of this command is: "Error during call to mysql_check", and the error in mysql log is the same.